# Insert into SQL Server TempDb from Microsoft Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

A Microsoft Access application excutes a stored procedure, that creates a table in tempDb and returns an empty recordset from that temp-table. The user of an Microsoft Access database should now be able to INSERT new records into this recordset. But the insert fails.

The first step of creating and selecting the temp table works fine:

```
    CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable
    (
      ID int DEFAULT (-1) NOT NULL,
      Column1 time(0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
      Column2 tinyint CHECK (Column2 <= 100) NOT NULL
    );
    SELECT * FROM #MyTempTable;
```

But as soon as the user adds a new record in an Access Form and tries to save it, SQL-Server returns a message that it ignores the database "master" because of the usage of a temp table. But I can't save any records.

I turned on SQL Profiler to see what Microsoft Access does behind the scenes. It automatically generates the following SQL-Statement:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO "master".."#MyTempTable" (Column1","Column2") 
VALUES (@P1,@P2)',N'@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 tinyint',N'Test',10
```

It ssems to always add the name of the default database. Access thinks there is an error. The INSERT does not work.

Is it possible to define the SQL-Statements for an endless form on my own?
It just works fine in SQL Server Management Studio but not in Access.
I am using SQL Server 2012 with Microsoft Access 2010.

Thanks.

Comment: could you post the exact error from Access? also keep in mind: 1. a temp table with one # only can be accesses by the SPID who created it. 2.- If access closes and reopens the connection, the temp table will be destroyed. 3.- to access a temp table from another SPID use double hash ##. Run sp_who2 to see the SPIDs

Comment: Temporary tables are dropped when they go out of scope. Once the stored procedure is done executing, the table is gone. You can use a global temporary table to prevent it from going poof (`##MyTempTable`), but even that lasts only as long as a session, and you can't guarantee Access will continue to use the same session. A possible alternative is to generate unique tables yourself that you can manage the lifetime of, but I don't know if you can easily make Access handle dynamic table names.

Comment: A more interesting question might be, what do you hope to achieve with this? Even if Access can fill the temporary table, given that it *is* a temporary table, how do you expect it to hang around long enough to meaningfully use? This sounds like a problem you could conceivably solve within Access itself (for example, with an [in-memory dataset](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3846361/Create-In-Memory-ADO-Recordsets.htm)).

Comment: @Ricardo: The Error Message is:   "2701: Database name 'master' ignored, referencing object in tempdb"   I only Close the database connection when the user closes the access file.

Comment: Error 2701 is technically ignorable (`master..#MyTempTable` *does* work to access the table, if it exists), but if Access makes a problem of it, a global temp table wouldn't work either.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: Thanks. I would like to achieve the following: When the user has done all his Inputs he can choose to save or to cancel. If he cancels, I drop the temp table. Otherwise I can move the data from the temp table to the production table and drop the temp table.  Yes, an ADODB-in-Memory dataset would be my choice if this is not working.

Comment: When I set the Recordsets ActiveConnection to Nothing so it's In-Memory then I can add rows in the Access-Form. But now I have to impelement Logic to write the data in one Transaction to SQL-Server because it is not in TempDb. But this is no problem. Thanks Guys for the ideas.